# C++ - Conway's Game of Life & Stepping Backwards

Tags: c++, qt

**EDIT #2** - I'm done the previous state part. Now I need to my state algorithm so that the grid acts like a Toroidal Array. That is, the top/bottom and right/left edges wrap around.

Not sure how to do this, though. How would I change the nested-if's in thisTimer() to do this?

---

**EDIT** - Is the serialising really necessary? I see how it could work, but I just need a simple, if crude, solution for stepping backwards.

---

I was able to create a version Conway's Game of Life that either stepped forward each click, or just ran forward using a timer. (I'm doing this using Qt.)

Now, I need to be able to save all previous game grids, so that I can step backwards by clicking a button. I'm trying to use a stack, and it seems like I'm pushing the old gridcells onto the stack correctly. But when I run it in QT, the grids don't change when I click BACK.

I've tried different things for the last three hours, to no avail. Any ideas?

gridwindow.cpp - My problem should be in here somewhere. Probably the handleBack() func.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include "gridwindow.h"

using namespace std;

// Constructor for window. It constructs the three portions of the GUI and lays them out vertically.
GridWindow::GridWindow(QWidget *parent,int rows,int cols)
: QWidget(parent)
{
  QHBoxLayout *header = setupHeader();   // Setup the title at the top.
  QGridLayout *grid = setupGrid(rows,cols);  // Setup the grid of colored cells in the middle.
  QHBoxLayout *buttonRow = setupButtonRow();  // Setup the row of buttons across the bottom.
  QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout();  // Puts everything together.
  layout->addLayout(header);
  layout->addLayout(grid);
  layout->addLayout(buttonRow);
 setLayout(layout);
}

// Destructor.
GridWindow::~GridWindow()
{
 delete title;
}

// Builds header section of the GUI.  
QHBoxLayout* GridWindow::setupHeader()
{
 QHBoxLayout *header = new QHBoxLayout();   // Creates horizontal box.
 header->setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);

 this->title = new QLabel("CONWAY'S GAME OF LIFE",this);    // Creates big, bold, centered label (title): "Conway's Game of Life."
  this->title->setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);
  this->title->setFont(QFont("Arial", 32, QFont::Bold));

  header->addWidget(this->title);  // Adds widget to layout.

  return header;      // Returns header to grid window.
}

// Builds the grid of cells.  This method populates the grid's 2D array of GridCells with MxN cells.
QGridLayout* GridWindow::setupGrid(int rows,int cols)
{
 isRunning = false;
 QGridLayout *grid = new QGridLayout();  // Creates grid layout.

  grid->setHorizontalSpacing(0);    // No empty spaces. Cells should be contiguous.
  grid->setVerticalSpacing(0);
  grid->setSpacing(0);
  grid->setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);

  for(int i=0; i < rows; i++)      //Each row is a vector of grid cells.
  {
   std::vector<GridCell*> row;     // Creates new vector for current row.
   cells.push_back(row);
   for(int j=0; j < cols; j++)
   {
    GridCell *cell = new GridCell();  // Creates and adds new cell to row.
    cells.at(i).push_back(cell);

    grid->addWidget(cell,i,j);    // Adds to cell to grid layout. Column expands vertically.
    grid->setColumnStretch(j,1);
   }
  grid->setRowStretch(i,1);     // Sets row expansion horizontally.
  }
  return grid;         // Returns grid.
}

// Builds footer section of the GUI.  
QHBoxLayout* GridWindow::setupButtonRow()
{
 QHBoxLayout *buttonRow = new QHBoxLayout();  // Creates horizontal box for buttons.
 buttonRow->setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);

 // Clear Button - Clears cell; sets them all to DEAD/white.
  QPushButton *clearButton = new QPushButton("CLEAR");
  clearButton->setFixedSize(100,25); 
  connect(clearButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(handlePause()));   // Pauses timer before clearing. 
 connect(clearButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(handleClear()));   // Connects to clear function to make all cells DEAD/white.
  buttonRow->addWidget(clearButton);   

 // Forward Button - Steps one step forward.
  QPushButton *forwardButton = new QPushButton("FORWARD");
  forwardButton->setFixedSize(100,25); 
  connect(forwardButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(handleForward()));   // Signals to handleForward function.. 
  buttonRow->addWidget(forwardButton); 

 // Back Button - Steps one step backward.
  QPushButton *backButton = new QPushButton("BACK");
  backButton->setFixedSize(100,25); 
  connect(backButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(handleBack()));   // Signals to handleBack funciton. 
  buttonRow->addWidget(backButton); 

 // Start Button - Starts game when user clicks. Or, resumes game after being paused.
 QPushButton *startButton = new QPushButton("START/RESUME");
  startButton->setFixedSize(100,25);   
 connect(startButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(handlePause()));   // Deletes current timer if there is one. Then restarts everything.
  connect(startButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(handleStart()));   // Signals to handleStart function.
  buttonRow->addWidget(startButton);

 // Pause Button - Pauses simulation of game.
  QPushButton *pauseButton = new QPushButton("PAUSE");
  pauseButton->setFixedSize(100,25);     
  connect(pauseButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(handlePause()));   // Signals to pause function which pauses timer.
  buttonRow->addWidget(pauseButton); 

  // Quit Button - Exits program.
  QPushButton *quitButton = new QPushButton("EXIT");
 quitButton->setFixedSize(100,25); 
 connect(quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));     // Signals the quit slot which ends the program.
  buttonRow->addWidget(quitButton);

  return buttonRow;    // Returns bottom of layout.
}

/*
 SLOT method for handling clicks on the "clear" button. 
 Receives "clicked" signals on the "Clear" button and sets all cells to DEAD.
*/
void GridWindow::handleClear()
{

   for(unsigned int row=0; row < cells.size(); row++)   // Loops through current rows' cells.
 {
 for(unsigned int col=0; col < cells[row].size(); col++)  // Loops through the rows'columns' cells.
  {
   GridCell *cell = cells[row][col];     // Grab the current cell & set its value to dead.
   cell->setType(DEAD);        
  }
 }
} 

/*
 SLOT method for handling clicks on the "start" button. 
 Receives "clicked" signals on the "start" button and begins game simulation.
*/
void GridWindow::handleStart()
{
 isRunning = true;             // It is running. Sets isRunning to true.
 this->timer = new QTimer(this);          // Creates new timer.
 connect(this->timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timerFired()));  // Connect "timerFired" method class to the "timeout" signal fired by the timer.
 this->timer->start(500);           // Timer to fire every 500 milliseconds.
}

/*
 SLOT method for handling clicks on the "pause" button. 
 Receives "clicked" signals on the "pause" button and stops the game simulation.
*/
void GridWindow::handlePause()
{
 if(isRunning)     // If it is running...
  this->timer->stop();  // Stops the timer.
 isRunning = false;    // Set to false.

}

void GridWindow::handleForward()
{
 if(isRunning);     // If it's running, do nothing.
 else
  timerFired();    // It not running, step forward one step.
}

void GridWindow::handleBack()
{
 std::vector<std::vector<GridCell*> > cells2;
 if(isRunning);     // If it's running, do nothing.
 else if(backStack.empty())
  cout << "EMPTYYY" << endl;
 else
 {
 cells2 = backStack.peek();
  for (unsigned int f = 0; f < cells.size(); f++)     // Loop through cells' rows.
  {
    for (unsigned int g = 0; g < cells.at(f).size(); g++)  // Loop through cells columns.
    {
     cells[f][g]->setType(cells2[f][g]->getType()); // Set cells[f][g]'s type to cells2[f][g]'s type.
    }
  }
 cout << "PRE=POP" << endl;
 backStack.pop();
 cout << "OYYYY" << endl;
 }  
}

// Accessor method - Gets the 2D vector of grid cells.
std::vector<std::vector<GridCell*> >& GridWindow::getCells()
{
 return this->cells;
}

/*
 TimerFired function:
  1) 2D-Vector cells2 is declared.
  2) cells2 is initliazed with loops/push_backs so that all its cells are DEAD.
  3) We loop through cells, and count the number of LIVE neighbors next to a given cell. 
   --> Depending on how many cells are living, we choose if the cell should be LIVE or DEAD in the next simulation, according to the rules.
   -----> We save the cell type in cell2 at the same indice (the same row and column cell in cells2).
  4) After check all the cells (and save the next round values in cells 2), we set cells's gridcells equal to cells2 gridcells.
   --> This causes the cells to be redrawn with cells2 types (white or black).
*/  
void GridWindow::timerFired()
{
 backStack.push(cells);
 std::vector<std::vector<GridCell*> > cells2;    // Holds new values for 2D vector. These are the next simulation round of cell types.
 for(unsigned int i = 0; i < cells.size(); i++)    // Loop through the rows of cells2. (Same size as cells' rows.)
 {
     vector<GridCell*> row;         // Creates Gridcell* vector to push_back into cells2.
     cells2.push_back(row);         // Pushes back row vectors into cells2.
     for(unsigned int j = 0; j < cells[i].size(); j++)  // Loop through the columns (the cells in each row).
     {
   GridCell *cell = new GridCell();     // Creates new GridCell.
   cell->setType(DEAD);        // Sets cell type to DEAD/white.
   cells2.at(i).push_back(cell);      // Pushes back the DEAD cell into cells2.
  }              // This makes a gridwindow the same size as cells with all DEAD cells.
  }

     for (unsigned int m = 0; m < cells.size(); m++)   // Loop through cells' rows.
     {
         for (unsigned int n = 0; n < cells.at(m).size(); n++) // Loop through cells' columns.
         {
             unsigned int neighbors = 0;      // Counter for number of LIVE neighbors for a given cell.

   // We know check all different variations of cells[i][j] to count the number of living neighbors for each cell.
   // We check m > 0 and/or n > 0 to make sure we don't access negative indexes (ex: cells[-1][0].)
   // We check m < size to make sure we don't try to access rows out of the vector (ex: row 5, if only 4 rows).
   // We check n < row size to make sure we don't access column item out of the vector (ex: 10th item in a column of only 9 items).
    // If we find that the Type = 1 (it is LIVE), then we add 1 to the neighbor.
    // Else - we add nothing to the neighbor counter.
    // Neighbor is the number of LIVE cells next to the current cell.
   if(m > 0 && n > 0)
   {
    if (cells[m-1][n-1]->getType() == 1)   
     neighbors += 1;
   }
   if(m > 0)
   {
    if (cells[m-1][n]->getType() == 1) 
     neighbors += 1;
    if(n < (cells.at(m).size() - 1))
    {
     if (cells[m-1][n+1]->getType() == 1) 
      neighbors += 1;
    }
   }
   if(n > 0)
   {
    if (cells[m][n-1]->getType() == 1) 
     neighbors += 1;
     if(m < (cells.size() - 1))
     {
      if (cells[m+1][n-1]->getType() == 1) 
       neighbors += 1;
     }
   }
   if(n < (cells.at(m).size() - 1))
   {
    if (cells[m][n+1]->getType() == 1) 
     neighbors += 1;
            }
   if(m < (cells.size() - 1))
   {
    if (cells[m+1][n]->getType() == 1) 
     neighbors += 1;
            }
   if(m < (cells.size() - 1) && n < (cells.at(m).size() - 1))
   {
    if (cells[m+1][n+1]->getType() == 1) 
     neighbors += 1;
   } 

   // Done checking number of neighbors for cells[m][n]
   // Now we change cells2 if it should switch in the next simulation step.
   // cells2 holds the values of what cells should be on the next iteration of the game.
   // We can't change cells right now, or it would through off our other cell values.
    // Apply game rules to cells: Create new, updated grid with the roundtwo vector.
    // Note - LIVE is 1; DEAD is 0.
    if (cells[m][n]->getType() == 1 && neighbors < 2)    // If cell is LIVE and has less than 2 LIVE neighbors -> Set to DEAD.
                cells2[m][n]->setType(DEAD);
             else if (cells[m][n]->getType() == 1 && neighbors > 3)   // If cell is LIVE and has more than 3 LIVE neighbors -> Set to DEAD.
                cells2[m][n]->setType(DEAD);
             else if (cells[m][n]->getType() == 1 && (neighbors == 2 || neighbors == 3)) // If cell is LIVE and has 2 or 3 LIVE neighbors -> Set to LIVE.
                cells2[m][n]->setType(LIVE);
             else if (cells[m][n]->getType() == 0 && neighbors == 3)  // If cell is DEAD and has 3 LIVE neighbors -> Set to LIVE.
                cells2[m][n]->setType(LIVE);  
   }
  }

  // Now we've gone through all of cells, and saved the new values in cells2.
  // Now we loop through cells and set all the cells' types to those of cells2.
  for (unsigned int f = 0; f < cells.size(); f++)     // Loop through cells' rows.
    {
     for (unsigned int g = 0; g < cells.at(f).size(); g++) // Loop through cells columns.
     {
      cells[f][g]->setType(cells2[f][g]->getType()); // Set cells[f][g]'s type to cells2[f][g]'s type.
     }
    }
}
```

stack.h - Here's my stack.

```
#ifndef STACK_H_
#define STACK_H_
#include <iostream>
#include "node.h"

template <typename T>
class Stack
{
 private:
  Node<T>* top;
  int listSize;

 public:
  Stack();
  int size() const;
  bool empty() const;  
  void push(const T& value);
  void pop();
  T& peek() const;
};

template <typename T>
Stack<T>::Stack() : top(NULL) 
{
  listSize = 0;
}

template <typename T>
int Stack<T>::size() const
{
  return listSize;
}

template <typename T>
bool Stack<T>::empty() const
{
  if(listSize == 0)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}

template <typename T>
void Stack<T>::push(const T& value)
{
 Node<T>* newOne = new Node<T>(value);
 newOne->next = top;
 top = newOne;
 listSize++;
}

template <typename T>
void Stack<T>::pop()
{
  Node<T>* oldT = top;
  top = top->next;
  delete oldT;
  listSize--;
}

template <typename T>
T& Stack<T>::peek() const
{
  return top->data;
  // Returns data in top item.
}

#endif
```

gridcell.cpp - Gridcell implementation

```
#include <iostream>

#include "gridcell.h"

using namespace std;

// Constructor: Creates a grid cell.
GridCell::GridCell(QWidget *parent)
: QFrame(parent)
{ 
 this->type = DEAD;    // Default: Cell is DEAD (white).
 setFrameStyle(QFrame::Box);  // Set the frame style.  This is what gives each box its black border.

 this->button = new QPushButton(this);   //Creates button that fills entirety of each grid cell.
 this->button->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Expanding);   // Expands button to fill space.
 this->button->setMinimumSize(19,19); //width,height         // Min height and width of button.

 QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout();    //Creates a simple layout to hold our button and add the button to it.
 layout->addWidget(this->button);
 setLayout(layout);

 layout->setStretchFactor(this->button,1);  // Lets the buttons expand all the way to the edges of the current frame with no space leftover
 layout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
 layout->setSpacing(0);

 connect(this->button,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(handleClick())); // Connects clicked signal with handleClick slot.
 redrawCell();   // Calls function to redraw (set new type for) the cell.
}

// Basic destructor. 
GridCell::~GridCell()
{
 delete this->button;
}


// Accessor for the cell type.
CellType GridCell::getType() const
{
 return(this->type);
}

// Mutator for the cell type.  Also has the side effect of causing the cell to be redrawn on the GUI.
void GridCell::setType(CellType type)
{
 this->type = type;
 redrawCell();   // Sets type and redraws cell.
}

// Handler slot for button clicks.  This method is called whenever the user clicks on this cell in the grid.
void GridCell::handleClick()
{         // When clicked on...
  if(this->type == DEAD)   // If type is DEAD (white), change to LIVE (black).
    type = LIVE;
  else 
 type = DEAD;     // If type is LIVE (black), change to DEAD (white).

  setType(type);         // Sets new type (color). setType Calls redrawCell() to recolor.
}

// Method to check cell type and return the color of that type.  
Qt::GlobalColor GridCell::getColorForCellType()
{
 switch(this->type)
 {
  default:
  case DEAD:
   return Qt::white;
  case LIVE:
   return Qt::black;
 }
}


// Helper method. Forces current cell to be redrawn on the GUI.  Called whenever the setType method is invoked.
void GridCell::redrawCell()
{
 Qt::GlobalColor gc = getColorForCellType();   //Find out what color this cell should be.
 this->button->setPalette(QPalette(gc,gc));   //Force the button in the cell to be the proper color.
 this->button->setAutoFillBackground(true);
 this->button->setFlat(true);      //Force QT to NOT draw the borders on the button
}
```

Thanks a lot. Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to [serialise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) (fairly comprehensive article) the game state at each step (for each player, or globally, or both - global undo?) and then push that serialised state. Then when you need to step backwards, you simply restore the correct state and deserialise it.

An added bonus to proper serialisation is that to save the game, you simply take the stack of serialised states and write it to a file, and to load a game you restore the stack of serialised states.

Comment: Could work... as long as the serialization code is smart enough to exclude the buttons that are part of his fundamental state class, `GridCell`.

Comment: Right. Or if the code is reworked to no longer use Buttons in GridCell.

Comment: Or perhaps completely reworked to contain game state in a proper state class. Separation of GUI and game logic/state is important.

Comment: @Matthew: Is there any easier way? My teacher told us that we need to remember the previous states using a Stack. So, how would I do that?

Comment: You don't necessarily *need* to serialise the data, you could just store old game state objects on the stack (as long as you create a new one for each step). You still need to separate game state and GUI code before that will work however.

Comment: Thanks, dude. I actually found a simple fix: I created a 2D Vector of ints, and stored the previous game states using 1 if a cell was LIVE and 0 if DEAD.

I just added another question in the post (via edit), in case you've got an idea for that as well.

Comment: In effect by creating a 2D vector you're moving the game state to an external entity, unlinking it from your GUI. It's not necessarily *ideal*, but it's a step in the right direction. As for you newest edit, you may want to move it out into a new question rather than continually update this one.

Answer (score 2):

You're storing vectors of pointers.  When you restore them, you restore the pointers themselves but not the data pointed to.

You're allocating a lot of new GridCell objects in timerFired, adding them to the cells2 data structure, and then you leak them.  All of them.  After overwriting the content pointed to by the pointers you saved.

Your underlying problem is conflating Model and View.  You've got Buttons inside your fundamental data structure, which is why you can't just swap it for a brand new matrix.

EDIT: Wait a sec, those GridCell instance being leaked... are GUI Frame widgets?  I'm surprised the simulation runs forward properly, let alone undo functionality.  Maybe Qt doesn't allocate GUI resources until the instance is parented.  You're using GridCell in two very different ways, which is demonstrated by the two constructors, and this is a very bad code smell.

Comment: +1 - nice catch on Buttons in the data structure - definitely makes saving and restoring state harder.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the toroidal mapping, you could append an else to each of the relevant if statements, handling the edge conditions.

I think I'd do it a little differently personally - store the addresses of the adjacent columns and rows, handling edge conditions, and then I have a uniform way of looking at adjacent cells using that.